# Chart.js chart not displaying until I open the browser's console

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I was trying to create a simple chart that displays covid-19 data with chart.js, but for some reason the code I wrote up was not working. The chart is empty upon loading the page, but if I open up the browser's console, the data suddenly shows up. And if I load the page with the console open, the chart is still empty, but if I close the console, the chart is filled.

Here is what it looks like upon loading the page with the console open: [empty chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spV7f.jpg)

And here is what it looks like immediately after I close the console: [filled chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOoeQ.jpg)

The following is all the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Playing with Covid19 data</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="deathChart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
    
    <script>
        const api_url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/us/daily"
        let dates = [], 
            deaths =[], 
            hospitalizations = [], 
            negatives = [], 
            positives = [], 
            recoveries = [], 
            onVentilatorCurrently_list = []


        function getData()
        {
            console.log("About to fetch the data")
            fetch(api_url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                for(let row of data){
                    let {date, death, hospitalized, negative, onVentilatorCurrently, positive, recovered} = row
                    dates.splice(0, 0, date)
                    deaths.splice(0, 0, death)
                    hospitalizations.splice(0, 0, hospitalized)
                    negatives.splice(0, 0, negative)
                    onVentilatorCurrently_list.splice(0, 0, onVentilatorCurrently)
                    positives.splice(0, 0, positive)
                    recoveries.splice(0, 0, recovered)
                }
                console.log("Finished fetching the data")
            })
        }

        getData()
        
        let death_config = {
                type: 'line',
                data:
                {
                    labels: dates,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "Deaths from Covid-19",
                            data: deaths,
                            fill: false,
                            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    tooltips: {
                    mode: "index",
                    intersect: false,
                    },
                }
            }
        let death_ctx = document.getElementById('deathChart').getContext('2d')
        let deathChart = new Chart(death_ctx, death_config)
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Does the data show up if you resize your window? Sometimes opening or closing the console is just resizing the window which is causing the data to load for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think you are loading the data before the chart is finished rendering. When you open/close the console it is resizing the window which triggers a re-render and shows the data properly. You can fix this by creating the chart after the data is done loading.

Edit: Changed to call `chart.update()` per OP's request.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Playing with Covid19 data</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="deathChart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>

  <script>
    const api_url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/us/daily"
    let dates = [],
      deaths = [],
      hospitalizations = [],
      negatives = [],
      positives = [],
      recoveries = [],
      onVentilatorCurrently_list = []


    function getData(chart) {
      console.log("About to fetch the data")
      fetch(api_url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          for (let row of data) {
            let {
              date,
              death,
              hospitalized,
              negative,
              onVentilatorCurrently,
              positive,
              recovered
            } = row
            dates.splice(0, 0, date)
            deaths.splice(0, 0, death)
            hospitalizations.splice(0, 0, hospitalized)
            negatives.splice(0, 0, negative)
            onVentilatorCurrently_list.splice(0, 0, onVentilatorCurrently)
            positives.splice(0, 0, positive)
            recoveries.splice(0, 0, recovered)
          }
          console.log("Finished fetching the data")
          chart.update();
        })
    }

    let death_config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: dates,
        datasets: [{
          label: "Deaths from Covid-19",
          data: deaths,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        tooltips: {
          mode: "index",
          intersect: false,
        },
      }
    }

    let death_ctx = document.getElementById('deathChart').getContext('2d')
    let deathChart = new Chart(death_ctx, death_config)

    getData(deathChart);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually, is there another way where I don't have to modify the getData() function? like if I made the chart right after I called the function?

Comment: @ahe So I updated the snippet. You can pass the chart into `getData()` and just call `chart.update()`. This still modifies the `getData()` function but is a bit more flexible. You can't really do it without adding some type of callback in `getData()` but if this is a problem let me know.

Comment: Yeah this seems to work great! However, I added this to my Vue project that I am working on, and all of a sudden it doesnt even display a chart at all. Is it cool if I send you the files to look at?

Comment: @ahe if you can put it into code sandbox or an online IDE so I can debug it there, I'll take a look. But also we are moving into general debugging of your app now. I think you should potentially accept an answer for this question and post new ones as needed since we solved your original problem.

Comment: You're right. I actually just used the first edit to your answer and that worked well for my Vue project, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check

```js
              
        const api_url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/us/daily";

        let dates = [], 
            deaths =[], 
            hospitalizations = [], 
            negatives = [], 
            positives = [], 
            recoveries = [], 
            onVentilatorCurrently_list = []


        function getData(){
          
            console.log("About to fetch the data")
            fetch(api_url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                for(let row of data){
                    let {date, death, hospitalized, negative, onVentilatorCurrently, positive, recovered} = row
                    dates.splice(0, 0, date)
                    deaths.splice(0, 0, death)
                    hospitalizations.splice(0, 0, hospitalized)
                    negatives.splice(0, 0, negative)
                    onVentilatorCurrently_list.splice(0, 0, onVentilatorCurrently)
                    positives.splice(0, 0, positive)
                    recoveries.splice(0, 0, recovered)
                }
                console.log("Finished fetching the data")
            })
        }

        getData()
        
        let death_config = {
         
                type: 'line',
                data:
                {
                    labels: dates,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "Deaths from Covid-19",
                            data: deaths,
                            fill: false,
                            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    tooltips: {
                    mode: "index",
                    intersect: false,
                       responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true
                    },
                }
            }

let death_ctx = document.getElementById('deathChart').getContext('2d')
let deathChart = new Chart(death_ctx, death_config)

setTimeout(function() { deathChart.update(); },1000);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">



<div><canvas id="deathChart" width="100" height="50"></canvas></div>
```